# react js and laravel too many request

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, request

I have too many request when i use  a function request in a map

```js
import qui from '../../Fonctions/Message/qui'

const cookies = new Cookies()

export default function MessageRecu() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([])
  const [affichage, setAffichage] = useState("")
  useEffect(() => {

    afficher(setMessage);

  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="container" style={premier.cadre}>
    <h2>Message</h2> 
    <Link to="/messageAjout" className="btn btn-danger right">Envoyer un message</Link>
    <Link to="/messageEnvoyer" style={{marginLeft:"2%"}} className="btn btn-warning right">message envoyé</Link>

    <table className="table  table-dark" style={{textAlign:"center",borderRadius:"3px",marginTop:"10px"}}>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">titre</th>
        <th scope="col">date</th>
        <th scope="col">de</th>
        <th scope="col">repondre</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {message.map((item,i) => (
         <>  {qui(setAffichage,item.user_id)}  //this is my  function but its repeat himself too many once
          <tr  key={item.id} >
            <td>{item.titre}</td>
              <td>{item.date}  </td>
              <td>{affichage}</td>
            </tr>
          </>
      ))}
    </tbody></table></div>
  );
}
```

i use laravel api,  how i can do for to avoid the message too many request
my purpose whit the function qui its to have whit user_id his name and email

function qui

```html
export default function qui(message,id){

    
 fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/message/qui?remember_token="+cookie.get("token")+"&id="+id,
    {

        header:{
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        },
        method:'POST'
    })
    .then((response) =>{

        if(response.ok){

            console.log("status ok")
            return response.text()
        }
        else{
            throw " probleme d affichage"
        }
    })
    .then((json)=>{

        message(json)
   
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
       // message(error)
       console.log("ici"+error)
    })
```

that return a string each time that it get a id

but i have a error i 429 i thinks  to many request after 2 minut

in message i have juste 2 array

Comment: Hey thank you for posting. Can you please make the question a bit clearer. Currently it is hard to look at  what is happening. 1 more thing can u post logic for qui function as this is what causing the issue as per your saying.

Comment: On the message.map there is a qui() function allowing to get the name and first name via a fetc, the problem is that it repeats itself infinitely and I have after 3 minutes to many request with the qui() function

Comment: sorry man! but it is unclear for me to answer and I need to look at qui function.